# Why wasn't the "American Ministry of Magic" given its correct title?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Why is the American magical government called

> American Ministry of Magic

in the second movie? To me if anything it should be MACUSA or maybe the American Department of Magic like the real world example Department of Defense, etc. Maybe Rowling doesn't know how our government works or she did not research like usual.

Comment: What makes you think Rowling decided what was in each subtitle?

Comment: Americans doing something non-standard and inconsistent? That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: In our defense, at least we're consistently inconsistent, and we do *try* to [standarize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) our non-standards ;-)

Comment: Too short for an answer, but as far as I understand, it is not an official government body, so why should it follow the naming convention of one?

Answer (score 25):

The subtitle is merely for the audience's benefit and convenience. The official title of the body is ["*The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA)*"](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa) however the majority of viewers wouldn't necessarily know what the acronym means. Note that the screenplay gives its full title

> **SCENE 1**
>   
> **EXT. NEW YORK, AMERICAN MINISTRY OF MAGIC—1927—NIGHT**
>
> *AERIAL SHOT of New York and MACUSA building.*

By the same token, the subtitle later in the film reads

> **French Ministry of Magic**

Whereas we know from various factbooks that the official title of the body is *"(le) Ministère des Affaires Magiques de la France"*. Again, the majority of viewers don't speak French so it's convenient to have the film explain where the characters are in a way that audiences (young and old) can easily comprehend.

Comment: yes I know what MACUSA is spelled out I just abbreviated it for the question. Still we have never used the title "Ministry" in our government  for its various departments since the founding of the United States.

Comment: @dean1957 - Can't help you with that one. It's simply a shorthand for punters who'd likely be familiar with the "Ministry of Magic" from the previous film series

Comment: But, if I remember correctly, the 1st part already prominently featured the MACUSA (and called it as such). Did they already call it "American Ministry of Magic" there, too?

Comment: Also, to a layman in French, the official French name isn't really far off the "French Ministry of Magic" either (besides being in a different language and thereby even more inapplicable for direct use).

Comment: No they called it MACUSA or used its long name Magical Congress .... in the first film and no subtitles for the identification of the American equivalent of the British Ministry of Magic either. Just a side note the Woolworth Building at the time of the film was suppose to be taking place 1926/27, was the worlds tallest building from 1913 - 1930.

Comment: @dean1957 Yeah, the UK uses 'ministry' because they're ministers of the monarch. The U.S. has no monarch, so it wouldn't make any sense to call a government agency a 'ministry' here. Instead, they're just called departments, which makes more sense in the context of a constitutional republic.

Comment: A "ministry" to Americans would be a "church" as operation/organisation (not as building).

Comment: @reirab Actually, today, all our government departments are called Departments, except for the Ministry of Defence, the Ministry of Justice and the Ministry of Housing, Communities and Local Government. (And the anachronism that the inspection system for vehicle roadworthiness is known as the MoT -- Ministry of Transport -- test, rather than the Department for Transport test.)

Comment: user3445853 I agree "ministry" has a more religious meaning here in the USA. david richerby since I am an American did not know that thanks for the information. Valorum- I have watched the movie twice and no subtitle was used here for the French Ministry of Magic , however it was spoken to Queenie went she went up to the desk to ask about Tina.

Answer (score 7):

If the MACUSA was founded in 1693 if I remember right, probably using a different name since there wasn't any USA yet, it would have been when the British colonies in North America were colonies of the English government, and the Kingdom of England in 1693 had ministries instead of departments.

So the magical government that later used the name MACUSA could have created a ministry to interact with the famous governments of the English colonies when necessary.  And if thy did so before the American Revolution in 1775-1783 they would have called it a ministry.  And maybe they didn't change the name of the ministry to department after the federal government of the USA was established in 1789.

Perhaps they wanted to avoid following the latest trends in muggle government and remain detached from muggle practices.